# How can I reference other nuget packages in my nuget package that will not be available to consumers of my nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have created .NET Core 3.1 class library project that will be published as a nuget package. Unfortunately it has to reference other nuget packages that cannot be made publicly available on nuget.org because of licensing issues.

How can I include those other nuget packages (or the assest/dlls of it) in my nuget package and at the same time prevent that the consumer of my nuget package automatically references the DLLs from the other nuget packages in his project.

The assest/DLLs from the other nuget packages need to be present in the user's application but its APIs should not be visible in the consumer's projects.

Or to put it in other words: I have purchased a library (they gave me a nupkg). I want to use it, but my customers should not.

Comment: That is not possible unless the package requires some kind of license key but it sounds like they are not your packages.

Comment: If the dependencies are also nuget packages, where are they published if not nuget.org? Another public feed? A private one?

Comment: I purchased a nupkg file.

Comment: You probably should just work with whoever provided you the package to understand their guidance on distributing their binaries.

Comment: Then you cannot publish a simple NuGet package. I am such a library vendor for commercial code, so my recommendation to the customers is that they should use tools like IL-Repack to link their libraries with mine, and I give them explicit rights to perform such merge. They can then pack up the merged ones as NuGet packages for redistributioin. Your vendor might have a similar policy, so you really should talk to them, not here.